# How do I set up a greater than filter by using a Form Web Part?

Tags: 2007, filter, data-view-web-part, form

I have a list that needs filters of greater than and lesser than an entered date.  I can connect the form web part to return the same date, but I need it to return the dates greater than or equal to the entered date within the form web part.  I have tried the Filter options on a Data View Web Part but it will not accept the values I have in the Form.  How can I filter dates using the Form Web Part?

Edit: This is only the Standard version, so I do not have Filter Web Parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by adding a DropDown and editing it as per [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sharepointdesigner/asp-net-controls-filter-the-data-view)